# Preventing map panning to last drawn marker using Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, markers

I have a basic Leaflet map where I need to draw several markers and lines on.
How do I prevent the map from panning to the last drawn object?

I've read about setting `autopan : False` for popups from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712637/how-can-i-prevent-leaflet-from-dragging-the-map-to-fit-marker-popups).

Can the `autopan : false` option work for leaflet markers?

Comment: Are you saying that you digitize a new element, and then the map automatically zooms to that element? And that you want to avoid that? If your code is not too long you might also want to share it, so it would be easier to solve the issue.

Comment: It's a pretty basic problem. I'll see if I can put together an example

Comment: That'd be nice. Just not entirely sure if I understood the question, hence I was asking.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you can.

```
var markerWithoutPan = new L.Marker([0, -10], {
    draggable: true,
    autoPan: false,
    title: 'NoPan'
});
```

[Source](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/debug/map/marker-autopan.html)

[Leaflet docs for Markers](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#marker)